# A second order recurrence relation problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was asked by a friend with this problem but I can't solve it. Can anyone help?

We have a sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ that satisfies $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$,

$$a_n+\frac{1}{a_n} =\frac{a_{n+1}^2+1}{a_{n+2}}$$

where $n$ is a positive integer.

Prove that

1. $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$
2. $2n-1\le a_n^2\le3n-2$
3. Let $S_n$ be the sum of the sequence $\left\{1\over a_n\right\}$, prove $62<S_{2014}<77$.

Comment: I'm sorry it should be <=3n-2

Comment: Yes.. the original question seems flawed, let's say it's <= here

Comment: Can you get the answer of (a) by induction?

Comment: My memory is quite rusty on induction. Could you briefly show how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a)**
By induction, assume $a_{k+1} =  a_k + \frac1{a_k}$. Then to get the result for $n=k+1$, consider
$$\begin{align*}
a_k+\frac1{a_k} =& \frac{a_{k+1}^2+1}{a_{k+2}}\\
a_{k+1}=&\frac{a_{k+1}^2+1}{a_{k+2}}\\
a_{k+2} =& a_{k+1}+\frac1{a_{k+1}}
\end{align*}$$

Also prove the base case for $n=1$ holds.

**(b)**
Using $a_{n+1}^2 = a_{n}^2+2+\dfrac1{a_n^2}$ and by induction, assume $2k-1\le a_k^2 \le 3k-2$. Then for $n=k+1$, the first inequality is
$$a_{k+1}^2 = a_k^2 + 2 +\frac1{a_k^2}\ge2k-1+2 = 2(k+1)-1$$
and the second inequality is similar. Use the fact that $0\le\dfrac1{a_k^2}\le1$.

**(c)**
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
2n+1\le&a_{n+1}^2&\le3n+1\\
\sqrt{2n+1}\le& a_{n+1} &\le \sqrt{3n+1}\\
\sqrt{2n+1}\le& a_1+\frac1{a_1}+\frac1{a_2}+\cdots+\frac1{a_n}&\le \sqrt{3n+1}\\
\sqrt{2\times2014+1}-a_1 \le& \sum_{i=1}^{2014}\frac1{a_i} &\le \sqrt{3\times2014+1}-a_1\\
62.4\cdots \le& \sum_{i=1}^{2014}\frac1{a_i} &\le 76.7\ldots\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Ok right, I understand (a) now. Just start with k=1 and generalize to n=k+1

Comment: I'm wondering if there's another way other than induction? Is it true that having $a_n+\frac{1}{a_n} =\frac{a_{n+1}^2+1}{a_{n+2}}$ is equivalent to having the first order relation $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$ ? Do we need to know $a_1$ and $a_2$ and use induction?

Comment: Yes, for (counter)example, if the sequence were given to start from $a_1=a_2=1$, then the sequence would still be defined by recursion, but your first order relation would not hold.

Comment: I see. Having the second order relation is a necessary but not sufficient condition for having the first order relation here.

Comment: OMG you are so good! This is a neat and beautiful solution! Thanks a lot!